# Sprintf takes more space than print?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, printf

I'm doing an Arduino sketch and I'm trying to gain some space. I saw on some websites that it's better to use `sprintf` than `print`. I tried but it takes way more space.

For example :

```
  char toWrite[18];
  sprintf(toWrite,"%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d",RTC.now().day(),RTC.now().month(),RTC.now().year()-2000,RTC.now().hour(),RTC.now().minute(),RTC.now().second());
  tft.println(toWrite);
```

takes more space than :

```
  tft.print(RTC.now().day(), DEC);
  tft.print('/');
  tft.print(RTC.now().month(), DEC);
  tft.print('/');
  tft.print(RTC.now().year(), DEC);
  tft.print(' ');
  tft.print(RTC.now().hour(), DEC);
  tft.print(':');
  tft.print(RTC.now().minute(), DEC);
  tft.print(':');
  tft.println(RTC.now().second(), DEC);
  tft.println();
```

Could someboby explain me why ?

Many thanks !

PS : Sorry for my English, it's not my mother tongue =)

Comment: What do you mean by space? On the screen? Memory? Exe size?

Comment: Use C++ streams instead, [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to be exact. `sprintf` is prone to buffer overruns and `printf` isn't flexible.

Comment: If you mean space for the routine, it's larger because it's more complicated and doing clever things to make your life easier, compared with print.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I don't believe the C++ STL is available on Arduino by default, you'd need a [separate library](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus/blob/master/README.md) for it.

Comment: Sorry to forgive that, I meant memory size

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees Oops, read that as Android not Arduino. ;)

Comment: If size is that big of an issue for you, read this about some alternative prototypes for smaller footprint forms of ***[(s/p)rintf functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16656893/645128)*** for embedded work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routine sprintf is larger because it is a more complicated (and more flexible) routine than print.  You can make your code smaller by having more arduous print statements.  Unfortunately, there is no free lunch in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can really cut down printf if you remove the extraneous formats.
Here is an example alternate fprintf (printf is just fprintf with 1 as first arg) that compiles down to 1/2kb including my conversion functions (it could be smaller if you remove more)

```
void myfprintf_(int fd,int nargs, ...){ 
   va_list ap; va_start(ap, nargs); static char *s; const char *fmt; 
   fmt=va_arg(ap, char *); 
   int i=0,p; 
   char buf[80]; 
while (fmt[i]){ 
   p=0; 
   while (fmt[i]!='%' && fmt[i]!=0) buf[p++]=fmt[i++]; 
   if (p != 0) write(fd,buf,p); 
   if (nargs-->0){ 
      switch (fmt[++i]) { 
      case 's': s=va_arg(ap, char *); break; 
      case 'd': s=dtos(va_arg(ap, int)); break; 
      case 'x': s=dtox(va_arg(ap, int),'a'); break; 
      case 'X': s=dtox(va_arg(ap, int),'A' ); break; 
      case 'f': s=ftos(va_arg(ap, double)); break; 
      case 'c': buf[0]=(va_arg(ap, int));buf[1]=0;s=buf;break; 
      case '%': s="%"; break; 
      default : s="";break; 
      } write(fd,s,strlen(s)); 
   } 
i++; 
} 
va_end(ap); 
}
```

just comment out the formats you won't need and modify for your existing conversion functions - Also if you want it to be more compliant, make it an int function vs void and sum the returns of write for the return value ... though 99% of the time I don't use printf's return.